# Use @RequestBody with optional body in latest Spring v4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httprequest

How do I make body optional in REST API calls when using `@RequestBody` annotation in Spring?

With Spring's latest version, if you use `@RequestBody` annotation, it makes client to send body all the time without making it optional.

I tried `@RequestBody (required=false)` but that didn't work & still my request comes as null.

How do I manage to get request converted to proper required object without making body mandatory?

For eg:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add/employee", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
    // ...
}
```

Here, I want to add employee using POST but without body. How do I do that? Spring latest version throws error "body missing" if I send empty body...

Answer (score 68, accepted):

@Santosh, I'm not sure which required argument you're referring. Mike already mentioned that he tried using `@RequestBody (required=false)` and request was still null. May be you can elaborate more & give example.

@Mike, probably you can try to have another separate converter that will serve your purpose.

Note: I noticed same issue with Spring v4.1.6 & Mike could be using that as he mentioned he is using latest version.

Answer (score 17):

I guess you are using spring version above 3.2 as there was a issue with the version. [@RequestBody should have a required parameter to allow a request body to be optional](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9239)

Have a look at following link
[Spring @RequestBody Anotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html)

`@RequestBody` Body takes and argument **required** which is true by default. Specifying it to false will help you

> public abstract **boolean required**
>
> Whether body content is required.
> **Default is true**, *leading to an exception thrown* in case there is no body content. Switch this to false if you prefer null to be passed when the body content is null.

Comment: When using a String as RequestBody(required = false) the default doesn't come as null, but as {} instead. Not sure why, but cost me some time and thought I'd share.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `java.util.Optional`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add/employee", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void addEmployee(@RequestBody Optional<Employee> employee){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: it's not advisable to use Optional type for params, intellij gives the message
see: https://www.wangler.io/blog/2017/java8-optionals.html#:~:text=Optional%20was%20designed%20to%20provide,to%20be%20Serializable%2C%20which%20java.

Comment: @alegria imo, that is a silly warning. Optional parameters can be very useful.

Comment: Optionals yes, but not as parameters

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I was trying to deserialize to a class called Customer marked as an Entity.  Because it contained a field pointing to another entity:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
   // ...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JsonManagedReference
   private List<Order> orders;
}
```

I kept getting a 415 error stating that application/json wasn't supported when trying to hit the following endpoint

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/customer")
public class Customer {
    // ...
    @PostMapping
    public void addNewCustomer(@RequestBody Customer cust) {
        customerService.createCustomer(cust);
    }
}
```

Replacing it with this worked:

```
record NewCustomerRequest(String name) {}

@PostMapping
public void addNewCustomer(@RequestBody NewCustomerRequest request) {
    Customer cust = Customer.builder()
            .name(request.name())
            .build();
    customerService.createCustomer(cust);
}
```