# How can I define two endpoints with the same mapping and request type but different parameters in OpenAPI 3.0.0 spec?

Tags: java, spring, openapi

Given the following classes:

```
public class Controller1 {

    @PostMapping(path = "endpoint/path/post", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<RandomObject> create(RandomObject randomObject) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(EVALUATION_DOMAIN)
public class Controller2 extends Controller1 {

    @PostMapping(path = "endpoint/path/post")
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createDifferent() throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

You'll notice the only difference between these methods (aside from the implementation) is that one takes a body and the other does not.

My problem becomes how to define such endpoints in the OpenAPI spec.

Ultimately, my purpose is to validate that each endpoint defined in the controllers has a definition in the relevant OpenAPI file. This is usually simple to do through a combination of the mapping and the request type.

However, as far as I can tell, the only way to define these methods would be to have something like this:

```
/endpoint/path/post:
  post:
    requestBody:
      required: false
```

My question is essentially this:

Is this the correct (expected) usage of the `required` property? Or is it meant for when the body is nullable?

If not, is there another way to define the endpoints in an unambiguous manner?

---

I could not find much in the [swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/) aside from this (rather unclear) sentence:

> Request bodies are optional by default. To mark the body as required, use required: true.

and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687616/use-requestbody-with-optional-body-in-latest-spring-v4) makes me think that "optional" is probably not meant as two different methods, but rather as a nullable body.

Side note: To be honest, I didn't even know spring-boot allowed you to define methods with the same mapping + method type, but apparently this code is in production and works as expected.

Comment: Does this even work as an actual endpoint in Spring? I doubt it's smart enough to know which endpoint you "meant" to hit.

Comment: @Jorn yeah I was shocked as well. But apparently it is smart enough. This code is quite old and is actively used by clients without issues ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Why don't you use that @RequestBody (required=false) ?

Comment: @Joan not entirely sure how that would help?

Comment: Sorry, not developing more my comment. But maybe if you define a single endpoint with @RequestBody(required = false). Then you can auto generate the open API documentation. (And so you will know the correct way to define it)

Comment: @Joan hmm I could try that, any particular plugin or library that you use to automatically generate OpenAPI files?

Comment: @Miss Skooter You could try this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code provided will work fine in Spring Boot. However it is not allowed according to the OpenAPI Specification. Hence you can't generate two different specifications for the same path/method combination.

> OpenAPI defines a unique operation as a combination of a path and an HTTP method. This means that two GET or two POST methods for the same path are not allowed – *even if they have different parameters (parameters have no effect on uniqueness)*.

Based on: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/

Answer (score -2):

one of your endpoints `(Controller1.create())` expects a `RandomObject` in the request body, and the other `(Controller2.createDifferent())` does not expect anybody. To define this in the OpenAPI specification, you should use required: true for the first endpoint and required: false (or simply omit the requestBody section) for the second.

The required attribute in the requestBody section of OpenAPI spec indicates whether the request body itself is required for the request, not if individual properties within the body are nullable or not. If it's set to true, the API endpoint expects a body in the request. If it's false, the API endpoint can be called without a body.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).